# Yield return and dynamic

Tags: c#, .net

Is possible to invoke a "IEnumerable/yield return" method when using dynamic?

I'm asking this because I'm getting the error below when I call the "Test(States1.GetNames())" method.

Error: "Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace YieldDemo
{
    public class States1
    {
          public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
        {
            yield return "Alabama";
            yield return "Alaska";
            yield return "Arizona";
            yield return "Arkansas";
            yield return "California";
            yield return "Others ...";
        }
    }

    public class States2
    {
        private static readonly IList<string> _names;

        static States2()
        {
            _names = new List<string>() {"Alabama", 
                                     "Alaska",
                                     "Arizona",
                                     "Arkansas",
                                     "California",
                                     "Others ..." };

        }

        public static IList<string> GetNames()
        {
            return _names;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {    
            Test(States2.GetNames());
            Test(States1.GetNames());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Test(dynamic state)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            Iterate(state);            
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }

        public static void Iterate(dynamic itemList)
        {
            var enumerator = itemList.GetEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @SLaks: No, it fails at runtime because of explicit interface implementation, I believe. (It's in the same assembly, so internals are fine.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the iterator block implementation uses *explicit interface implementation* to implement `IEnumerable<T>`... and explicit interface implementation doesn't play nicely with dynamic typing in general. (You don't need to use iterator blocks to see that. See [my article on Gotchas in Dynamic Typing](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter14/DynamicGotchas.aspx) for more details.)

You can iterate with `foreach` though:

```
public static void Iterate(dynamic itemList)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in itemList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

This has the additional benefit that it will dispose of the iterator for you, which your previous code didn't do :)

Alternatively, you add overloads for `Iterate` to take `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`, and let execution-time overload resolution within `Test` do the right thing (due to `state` being `dynamic` too).

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It fails because the `IEnumerable<string>` class generated by your `yield` code [explicitly implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) its interfaces (including the `GetEnumerator` you're trying to use). You can call the method like this:

```
public static void Iterate(dynamic itemList)
{
    var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)itemList).GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Or, since you don't need `dynamic` for any reason I can see here, maybe just:

```
public static void Iterate(IEnumerable itemList)
{
    var enumerator = itemList.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static void Iterate<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemList)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim S. for your answer